# what all are the jar dependencies for apache POI for read and write to excel or xls?

Tags: apache-poi

i am getting runtime with error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject because of missing xmlbeans.jar dependency.
i need to work with XLS, DOC and .PPT formats.
**Can somebody suggest the important JARs for the apache POI?**

Answer (score 3):

The dependencies of Apache POI are [fully described on the Apache POI website here](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

That table (which I won't reproduce here as you'll want to check the latest version [on the POI website](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)) details, for each component you want to use, what the dependencies are.

If you download the latest Apache POI binary release (`.tar.gz` or `.zip`), you'll find all the dependency jars you need contained within that. Check the [components and dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to see which ones you'll need for your use.

Alternately, manually handling dependencies is rather 1990s. You'd be much better off using a tool like Gradle or Apache Maven to handle it for you, then they'll pick up the project-supplied metadata to grab the dependencies you need.

Detail of the Maven / Gradle artifacts for Apache POI are also given on the [Components page on the POI website](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

Answer (score 0):

For Apache POI you need these two combination.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```