# Apache POI - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/utils/InputStreamStatistics

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-io, fileinputstream, apache-poi-4

I'm trying to read a word document (.docx) using Apache POI and it gives me this error...

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/utils/InputStreamStatistics
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:178)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:104)
>       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:301)
>       at gui.CryptoGUI.selectFileButtonActionPerformed(CryptoGUI.java:645)
>       at gui.CryptoGUI.access$1100(CryptoGUI.java:27)
>       at gui.CryptoGUI$11.actionPerformed(CryptoGUI.java:321)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at com.jtattoo.plaf.BaseButtonListener.mouseReleased(BaseButtonListener.java:65)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I have below libraries in my classpath,

[image]

This is the code which I'm getting this error

```
private void selectFileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
    int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            fileNameText.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            double bytes = selectedFile.length();
            double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
            fileSizeLabel.setText("Size : " + (Math.round(kilobytes * 100.0) / 100.0) + " KB");
            fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis)); // EXCEPTION THROWS FROM HERE
            XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(xdoc);
            System.out.println(extractor.getText());


        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CryptoGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CryptoGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CryptoGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CryptoGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like I'm missing a library but I think I have added everything I needed for this. What am I missing here?

Comment: You use commons-compress-1.9.0 .... InputStreamStatistics is since 1.17 maybe this fix this issue.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 - updated to commons-compress-1.19 and it worked. Wanna post this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use commons-compress-1.9.0 .... InputStreamStatistics is since 1.17 this maybe fix this issue.

Comment: updating `commons-compress` solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the linked question, a good resource is the POI page.  [what all are the jar dependencies for apache POI for read and write to excel or xls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165556/what-all-are-the-jar-dependencies-for-apache-poi-for-read-and-write-to-excel-or)

It seems unfortunately hard to get there from Google, or the Apache POI site itself.  http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components

The commons compress library version looks highly suspect.  The latest I see in search.maven.com is 1.19.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, @pL4Gu33 pointed out the `commons-compress` version first